# Can the user TPM be accessed through javascript in the browser?

Tags: tpm

I heard the TPM can be used for DRM purposes. But currently is there a way to access this module through the browser? or is it simply for native applications.

The only thing I came across searching was tpm-js, but this tutorial seems to be for js running outside the browser.

Has there been demonstration of TPM access to identify users through the browser?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Your closest bet is the [WebAuthN standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-tpm-attestation) but I'm also not aware of TPM support by major browsers. Let us know if you find something!